# How to fix Undefined: Property error setTargetNode

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently compiling my react project, and it compiles successfully however upon loading the page i get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTargetNode' of undefined
at p (Target.js:40)
at Ba (react-dom.production.min.js:5029)
at Ha (react-dom.production.min.js:5123)
at react-dom.production.min.js:5975
at Object.t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:274)
at Au (react-dom.production.min.js:5974)
at ju (react-dom.production.min.js:5958)
at Pu (react-dom.production.min.js:5925)
at Su (react-dom.production.min.js:5860)
at react-dom.production.min.js:5761
```

[image: Error]

The target.js I believe is a file from the react-popper node module. Which was working prior to updating the package file. The page loads all elements on the page load then the page goes totally blank.

I have tried deleting my package-locked.json and formed a new one however the issue still persists. The project however works fine in the dev environment.

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "compscout-sales",
  "version": "0.1.0",

  "private": true,

  "dependencies": {

    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.7",

    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.2.0",

    "@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",

    "@coreui/react": "^2.1.5",

    "axios": "^0.18.0",

    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",

    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",

    "bootstrap-less": "^3.3.8",

    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",

    "classnames": "^2.2.6",

    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",

    "core-js": "^2.6.5",

    "cors": "^2.8.5",

    "debug": "~2.6.9",

    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",

    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",

    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.10.0",

    "exceljs": "^0.8.2",

    "express": "~4.16.0",

    "express-rate-limit": "^3.5.1",

    "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",

    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",

    "http": "0.0.0",

    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",

    "https": "^1.0.0",

    "jade": "~1.11.0",

    "jquery": "^3.4.1",

    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",

    "moment": "^2.24.0",

    "morgan": "~1.9.0",

    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",

    "pg-promise": "^8.6.5",

    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",

    "ramda": "^0.26.1",

    "react": "^16.8.4",

    "react-apollo": "^2.5.6",

    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.2.1",

    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",

    "react-cookie": "^4.0.0",

    "react-dates": "^20.2.0",

    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",

    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",

    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",

    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",

    "react-router-config": "^4.4.0-beta.6",

    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",

    "react-select": "^2.4.3",

    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",

    "react-stripe-elements": "^3.0.0",

    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.4",

    "reactstrap": "^7.1.0",

    "redux": "^4.0.1",

    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",

    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",

    "request": "^2.88.0",

    "sequelize": "^5.8.7",

    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",

    "stripe": "^6.34.0",

    "xlsx": "^0.11.19"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"

  }, 

  "scripts": {

    "start": "react-scripts start",

    "start:server": "node ./server/www",

    "build": "react-scripts build",

    "test": "react-scripts test",

    "eject": "react-scripts eject"

  },

  "eslintConfig": {

    "extends": "react-app"

  },

  "browserslist": {

    "production": [

      ">0.2%",

      "not dead",

      "not op_mini all"

    ],

    "development": [

      "last 1 chrome version",

      "last 1 firefox version",

      "last 1 safari version"

    ]

  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Alternate to below answer, if you are still unable to fix the error, please share your code in target.js file so people can better help you

Comment: @iRohitBhatia apologies i should have mentioned this in the post target.js is a file from the react popper node modules

Comment: Discussion at https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper/issues/294

Answer (score 0):

what does `package.json` has to do with the described error? Read the error again, it describes exactly what is wrong: inside the file `Target.js` you are trying to access a property called `setTargetNode` of some object, and that object happened to be `undefined` when the code reached that point. it even points you to the exact line: `(Target.js:40)`.

Go there, follow the flow of data to that object- where it is created / initialized? are you sure it is initialized **before** the access to `setTargetNode` is happening? try it yourself first, if still no success please post the code related to the error so we can better help.

Comment: Target.js seems to be a react-popper (node module file) which worked prior to this then the aws just stopped compiling producing a reference undefined error so i updated my package-lock file and produced this error Thanks

Comment: oh so Target.js is not your file... are you using vsCode? if so, try to breakpoint on "uncaught exceptions" and watch the call stack. it should refer you (somewhere in there) to the point in your code which caused this internal `setTargetNode` to fail. Post the code snippet here, and if you don't find it you can also post the call stack and we can try to help from there

Comment: Im not using vsCode however i can use it. Its setup to run on a docker image with other thing im not quite sure how to get it running alone in vsCode. Thanks

Comment: this happens when you run from docker? don't you have a testing environment to run it directly from your local machine? what IDE do you use?

Comment: Yes i run in docker locally in the dev environment and it works fine but when i make the live build this happens. Also PHP storm

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem recently. this was resolved when i used an old package-lock.json. i think it was caused by some dependency packages. 
maybe "electron-to-chromium" or "timers-browserify"
Hope this would help you.